# Openpyxl get_column_letter ValueError

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am making an excel comparing tool in python. Here is my code:

bananacell.py:

```
import time

print("Welcome to Banana Cell the open source excel tool!")
time.sleep(1)
import compare
compare.main()
```

compare.py:

```
import openpyxl, tkinter, time
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


def main():
    print('Select file 1 from folder')
    root = Tk()
    filename = askopenfilename()
    root.withdraw()
    wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    names1 = input('Sheet 1 name: ')
    sheet1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name(str(names1))

    print('Select file 2 from folder')
    root1 = Tk()
    filename1 = askopenfilename()
    root1.withdraw()
    wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(filename1))
    names2 = input('Sheet 2 name: ')
    sheet2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name(str(names2))

    object1 = list(sheet1['A1':get_column_letter(sheet1.max_row)])
    object2 = list(sheet2['A1':get_column_letter(sheet2.max_row)])

    for i in object1:
        for x in object2:
            if i != x:
                print('Diff found!')
                print (i.value, i.coordinate)
                print (x.value, x.coordinate)
                print('----------')
                break
```

But I keep on getting this following ValueError:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you reached the limit of columns in the sheet.

[There's a limit](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/644ea21bb4056f93184d3e743f4abf05c51f84af/openpyxl/utils/cell.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#cell.py-79) of max 18,278 columns in the sheet supported by openpyxl, and [even less](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) in MS Office Excel (16,384) and Apple Numbers (only 255 columns).

You can add a checking to your code like:

```py
MAX_COLUMNS = 18278

if active_sheet.max_column > MAX_COLUMNS:
    raise ValueError(
        'Too many columns in the sheet, the limit is {}, found: {}'.format(
            MAX_COLUMNS,
            ctive_sheet.max_column,
        )
    )
```

Or make a [pull request to openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/) with supporting of bigger amount of columns :)

Comment: The specification sets the limit at 16,384 columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
object1 = list(sheet1['A1':get_column_letter(sheet1.max_row)])
```

You pass something like `sheet1['A1':D]`, you want `sheet1['A1':D1000]`

I belive this nesting loops will not work:
     `for i in object1:
        for x in object2:`